# Can Liquibase snapshot command generate data snapshot too

Tags: database, liquibase, snapshot

Liquibase [snapshot](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/snapshot.html) can generate a snapshot of the database schema, but can it do the same for data as well? If so, how?

While changesets support (in Pro or above version I guess) data, a snapshot command not generating data snapshot is kind of awkward I thought. Can someone please clarify?